# не понимаю как сделать загрузку и отправку информации в телеграмм боте

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Я хочу сделать телеграмм бота-скупку, и суть заключается в том, чтобы пользователь (продавец) зашёл в телеграмм бот, отправил туда информацию (фото, номер набора, пометки, цену), и вся эта информация отправлялась администратору бота в одном сообщение.

Как сделать так, чтобы эта информация куда-то сохранялась, и как ее дальше использовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, тебе пригодится какая-то база данных (sqlite3 например), и FSM, если планируешь получать сообщения по очереди

Comment: да, изначально сделал так, потом просто написал хендлер который отправляет все данные (фото, описание, номер и имя пользователя), который срабатывает после того, как пользователь ввёл все данные